# PHP/jQuery Unable to Send Email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

How can I send an email using PHP?

Here's the HTML:
I got it from a website, and it came with more jQuery and CSS. So, I'm wondering why it won't send the email. The PHP is below the HTML. JavaScript will be in a jsfiddle, because it's a lot. It came with: Name, Email, and Message, and I tried to add a Phone Number too, so that might be an issue. Ive tried so much and I just can't figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animateform.css">
</head>


<body>



<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="well" style="margin-top: 10%;">
    <h3>Send me a message</h3>
    <form role="form" id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required data-error="NEW ERROR MESSAGE">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="phone" class="h4">Phone</label>
                <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" required>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="h4 ">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right ">Submit</button>
        <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="Java/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Java/validator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Java/form-scripts.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

Now here's the PHP code, with my email erased (for obvious reasons).

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}


// PHONE
if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Phone is required ";
} else {
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "erased@gmail.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

validator.min.js: http://jsfiddle.net/4yujfv7L/

form-scripts.js
http://jsfiddle.net/tnz3so04/

And here's the CSS file:
Never mind I just started asking here so I can't post more than two links.

Comment: If you are using 000webhost you have to keep in mind that it is free hosting and your mail may be sometimes blocked by other users.

Comment: But usually it takes a few seconds for it to send right? It just finishes loading in like less than a second after I click submit

Comment: Aren't you missing action in your form tag ?

Comment: Do I need it? I was told it wasn't required

Comment: If you don't have action your form will be sent to same page. Do you have your php on same page as your html?

Comment: No a separate are page

Comment: then just add action = "your_separate_page.php" to your form. It seems that you have never gotten to your php script.

Comment: Palo, it gives this message after submit now even though i filled them in...Name is required Email is required Phone is required Message is required

Comment: You are also missing name attribute on your inputs.

Comment: for example : <input type = "text" type = "email" name = "email">

Comment: You also need to specify method = "POST" on your form because default method is GET.

Comment: Palo, it says success now but its not sending the email.